# Cannot configure NAP DCOM security

Tags: windows-server-2008, dcom

I've just added a new 2K8 domain controller to an existing domain as part of a transition from 2k3.  I am getting a lot of DCOM 10016 errors, indicating launch security permission problems on a specific CLSID, which ends up being the NAP Agent Service.
I've dealt with this before by granting the Network Service local launch and local activation permissions, but the secuirty options are all disabled for this component in the Component Services snap-in.
The NAP agent service is not running, and startup is set to Manual.
Any ideas on how to remove the errors for the unrequried NAP agent?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you do not have enough rights. Take the CLSID given in the error message. Search the registry for this id, you'll probably end up somewhere inside the hkey_classes_root. Take the Appid and again initiate a search inside HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID.
Right click the folder and change permissions, take ownership and give your account full control. You will now be able to change the greyed-out items.